# Using database with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

I'm a begginer in Express, I would like to understand how can I make a "Select *" (for exemple ) on a table.
I know that i have to make a model of the table in a .js file. And I understand the next steps.

But my question is : How can I make a model of the table if there are for example 200 columns? Because it would not be practical to use all 200 names.
I hope that the explanation of my problem is clear ^^

If someone could explain me how does it works !

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Sequelize you can use this [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) package to generate models automatically.